# retorno de una función

Tags: php, json, api

estoy intentando imprimir un datos de una api, y no soy capaz. Me muestra varios campos y solo quiero poder imprimir el nombre. os adjunto código

GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

function actionIndex(){
    $error = '';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:926724');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://pruebas.donquijote.com/api/clientes/1');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $error = curl_errno($ch);
    if($error){
        echo ("Error: ".$error);
    }
}
$var = actionIndex();
echo $var['nombre'];

//Esto me imprime
//{"id": 2,"clienteid": "00001","nombre": "Pepe"}

//Pero lo que quiero es imprimir solo el nombre, algo así como echo $var["nombre"]

?>
```

Comment: hay algo que no me cuadra; donde esta el return con el que llenas $var?

Comment: En eso mismo quedo, como llenas el $var acá ?? Cree una imitacion como array, la leo y todo ok... por lo que debe ser eso, pero no lo veo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que estas obteniendo es un `string` en formato `json` el cual tienes que `decodificar` (convirtiéndolo en un `objeto`) y luego convertir el `objeto` en `array` (yo usaría un `casteo`):

```php
    $json='{"id": 2,"clienteid": "00001","nombre": "Pepe"}';
    $jsonObj = (array) json_decode($json);
    echo $jsonObj['nombre'];
```

con esto resolvería tu pregunta pero veo que tienes otros posibles `errores` de sintaxis, en `php` siempre que llamas a un método y quieres obtener datos este debe tener un `return`, tu `código` debería lucir así:

```php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
function actionIndex(){
    $error = '';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:926724');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://pruebas.donquijote.com/api/clientes/1');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $json = curl_exec($ch);
    $error = curl_errno($ch);
    if($error){
        echo ("Error: ".$error);
        die;
    }else{
        curl_close($ch);
    }
    //$json='{"id": 2,"clienteid": "00001","nombre": "Pepe"}';
    $result = (array) json_decode($json);
 
    return $result;
}
$var = actionIndex();
echo $var['nombre'];
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127485/discussion-on-answer-by-francisco-nunez-todo-poderoso-retorno-de-una-funcion).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro cuanto tiempo dura ese chat???

Comment: El chat dura de forma indefinida. Se puede congelar si no hay actividad durante X tiempo, pero el chat en sí no se borra.

Comment: ok, gracias....